# asp.net Display a variable according to the language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

New in asp.NET (MVC), I looking for way to display the "right" variable according to the language of the user. To detect the language, I use Nadeem Afana's method and it does a very good job.

Example: I have out of my sql server table name_fr, name_en, name_de

In asp classic, I used to write the record set rs("name_"&session("lang"))
I could do with if statement for each language, but I would prefer the other approach in case I add a new language.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
//This is the model:
    public partial class ItemType
    {
        public int ItemTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Name_fr { get; set; }
        public string Name_en { get; set; }
        public string Name_de { get; set; }
    }

    // The controller
        public class ITemTypesController : BaseController
        {
            private DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

            // GET: Admin/ItemTypes
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(db.ItemType.ToList());
            }
        }

// The view
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name_fr)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name_en)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name_de)
        </td>

@UICulture // is the language identifier
```

Comment: What are you using to read data from your database?

Comment: Entity Framework

Comment: I don't know EF but, if you can, put your translations in a Dictionary<string, string> where your key is the language identifier.